# Dynamic form insert database

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

My whole signup page code is here.
[Link](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Sign-Up-Form-and-Email-Activation-PHP-MySQL-JavaScript-Programming-Tutorial)

I'm trying to add this dynamic fields to the signup page code.

```
<script>

 var i = 1;
 function addKid(){
    if (i <= 6){
      i++;
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.style.width = "44%";
 div.style.height = "26px";
 div.style.color = "white";
 div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
 div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input type="text" name="child_'+i+'" > Ages : <input type="text" name="ages_'+i+'"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
 document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
 }
 }
 function removeKid(div) {
     document.getElementById('kids').removeChild( div.parentNode );
 i--; }
```

```
         <div id="kids">
     Child : <input id="child_1" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('mwhen')" maxlength="50">

      Ages :  <input id="ages_1" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('mwhen')" maxlength="10"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" />
       </div>
```

I can get the "child_1 / chi" and "ages_1 / ags" insert into my database. no problem.

When I try to create a extra dynamic field in my signup, "child_2 and ages_2".....
then I can't get that info from "child_2 and ages_2" insert into my database.

Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong since I can't get that info into my database.? Am I suppose to call "child_2 / chi2" and "ages_2 / ags2" for something els before it will work.?

```
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$p = $_POST['p'];
$g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
$chi = preg_replace('#[^a-z.,-/ ]#i', '', $_POST['chi']);
$ags = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#i', '', $_POST['ags']);
$chi2 = preg_replace('#[^a-z.,-/ ]#i', '', $_POST['chi2']);
$ags2 = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#i', '', $_POST['ags2']);
$c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
// GET USER IP ADDRESS
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
// DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// -------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $chi == "" || $ags == "" || $chi2 == "" || $ags2 == "" || $c == ""){
```

..

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, child_1, ages_1, child_2, ages_2, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
            VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$chi','$ags','$chi2','$ags2','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
```

..

```
function restrict(elem){
var tf = _(elem);
var rx = new RegExp;
if(elem == "email"){
    rx = /[' "]/gi;
} else if(elem == "username"){
    rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
} else if(elem == "child_1"){
    rx = /[^a-z.,-/ ]/gi;
} else if(elem == "ages_1"){
    rx = /[^0-9.]/gi;
} else if(elem == "child_2"){
    rx = /[^a-z.,-/ ]/gi;
} else if(elem == "ages_2"){
    rx = /[^0-9.]/gi;
} 
tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
```

}
..

```
function signup(){
var u = _("username").value;
var e = _("email").value;
var p1 = _("pass1").value;
var p2 = _("pass2").value;
var c = _("country").value;
var chi = _("child_1").value;
var ags = _("ages_1").value;
var chi2 = _("child_2").value;
var ags2 = _("ages_2").value;
var g = _("gender").value;
var status = _("status");
if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || chi == "" || ags == "" || chi2 == "" || ags2 == "" || g == ""){
```

..

```
        }
    ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&chi="+chi+"&ags="+ags+"&chi2="+chi2+"&ags2="+ags2+"&g="+g);
}
```

..

Comment: how you are crating dynamic ?

Comment: if you are creating dynamic . you have to create different id . and if name is same then you have to use array[].

Comment: try to simplify your code and put. very to difficult to check all lines of code.

Comment: When I create my dynamic in my signup and then use firebug then I can see the are called child_1, child_2 , child_3 etc. same with ages_1, ages_2, ages_3 etc.

Comment: are you passing and retrieving it properly ?

Comment: ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&chi="+chi+"&ags="+ags+"&chi2="+chi2+"&ags2="+ags2+"&g="+g); you passing only tow age and child

Comment: @Vigneswaran S Thanks for taking the time to respond to me, *bow*. :-)  I'm not sure what else I can say to a pro guy like you, beside I wish that I had that knowledge you have right now and I'm not sure how to tackle this. Any chance you can show me what I'm doing wrong and where as I'm totally lost on this.? Thanks again for everything and I hope you will have a awesome day. :-)

Comment: Tried the dynamic field form in phpfiddle and with firebug I can see that those extra dynamic fields are called child_2  and ages_2...<pre><div class="myclass" style="width: 600px; height: 50px; color: white;">
Child :
<input type="text" name="child_2">
Ages :
<input type="text" name="ages_2">
<input id="add_kid()" type="button" value="+" onclick="addKid()">
<input type="button" onclick="removeKid(this)" value="-">
</div><code> So I thought if I just added child_2 and ages_2 like I did with the child_1 and ages_1 then I could also get that info into my database, but this is not working for me.

Comment: today after 10 pm i will try to solve your problem. so you also come and respond if possible. now i am in office cant help now

Comment: Thank you and I will do my best to be here, I hope you will have a good day at work. you are awesome.! :-)

Comment: can you send your db. i am running your code for your link. if possible export it and send the db file to vickysoft.1990@gmail.com

Comment: can you say table "users"  structure.if i have 5 child how can i insert data and where to insert

Comment: else for saving child use 5 column in your user table or use seprate table . show ur user structure

Comment: I had just send you a email with the information you asked for. Thanks

Comment: i need user table structure alone.

Comment: if you put your table structure, then only i  can solve your problem.

Comment: Hi and sorry for being late , work and kids etc... I had just send you a email and thanks.

Comment: so your table has only 2 child column to save.but you can create 6 child dynamically. then how to save the other child? or where to  save other child . shall  i create 6 extra column in user table. like child_1,child_2,child_3.....child_6.? or you can create a new table to save child. where user table ID will be as a foreign key.

Comment: I  had only made up to child_2 and ages_2 and was unsure if I did it correct since it did not worked for me, so I thought that there was no point to make up to child_6 and ages_6...but now I will create up to child_6 and ages_6 in my user table. Thanks once again and looking forward to hear from you. Have a great day.

Comment: Hi Vigneswaran, I had been trying to make it to work but can't and I'm wondering if you did manage to make it to work.? Have a great day. :-)

Comment: i will help dont worry . two days out of station

Comment: hi have you tried the code . let me know your difficulties

Comment: Hey I just got back and had not got time to tried it yet but working on it and I'm sure it's fine, thanks a lot for everything you had done, you are Awesome, thanks again. :-) oh yeah shame I can't give you a arrow up "this answer is useful" I need to earn a total of 15 reputation....thanks again for the help.

Comment: Got it and thanks, trying to add your code some how to my sign up page as seen above.  [link](http://developphp.com/video/PHP/Sign-Up-Form-and-Email-Activation-PHP-MySQL-JavaScript-Programming-Tutorial)

Comment: you have to use single select statement as  given in my answer. check it. up-vote for your question :)

Comment: Hey still working on it and did send you a email. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly save your child and age in array and pass it in ajax. so that you can loop the child and age as given below and insert it into table.

For password and conform password use js. and validate it in front end itself. save password alone in table that's enough.

try to understand this code and do alterations as required. but i sloved your dynamic child and age problem. run this code

page1.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#input_form").submit(function(){
             var querystring = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
            url: 'save_child.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: querystring,
            success: function(data) {
            alert("jhkl");
                    }
            });
                 //$('#result').html(querystring);
                 return false;
                 });
        });
    </script>
    <title>Serialize</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form  id="input_form">
        first name: <input type="text" name="username" id="first name"/><br />
     password: <input type="text" name="password" id="last name"/><br />
        email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br />
     <div id="kids">
     Child : <input id="child_1" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('mwhen')" maxlength="50" name="child[]">

      Ages :  <input id="ages_1" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('mwhen')" maxlength="10" name="ages[]"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" />
       </div>  

       <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html><script>

 var i = 1;
 function addKid(){
    if (i <= 5){
      i++;
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.style.width = "44%";
 div.style.height = "26px";
 div.style.color = "white";
 div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass');
 div.innerHTML = 'Child : <input type="text" name="child[]" > Ages : <input type="text" name="ages[]"><input type="button" id="add_kid()" onClick="addKid()" value="+" /><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeKid(this)">';
 document.getElementById('kids').appendChild(div);
 }
 }
 function removeKid(div) {
     document.getElementById('kids').removeChild( div.parentNode );
 i--; }
</script>
```

save_child.php

```
<?php
$child=$_REQUEST['child'];// child array
$ages=$_REQUEST['ages'];
$InputArray = array();
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tes");// data base connection


$InputArray['username']=$_REQUEST['username'];// get datas and store in a array named InputArray
$InputArray['password']=$_REQUEST['password'];
$InputArray['email']=$_REQUEST['email'];
$i=1;
foreach($child as $val){
$b=$i-1;
$InputArray['child_'.$i]=$val;
$InputArray['age_'.$i]=$ages[$b];
$i++;
}


$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userss` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `child_1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `age_1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `child_2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `age_2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `child_3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `age_3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `child_4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `age_4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `child_5` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `age_5` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ";

    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (count($InputArray) > 0) {
            while (list($key, $val) = each($InputArray)) {
                if(!empty($val)){
                    $fields.= $key . ',';
                    $valset.= "'". $val ."',";
                }
            }
        }   

        $fields = trim($fields, ',');
        $valset = trim($valset, ',');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO userss ($fields) VALUES ($valset)";

        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
```

Another one thing I have noted in your code.

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";

you have written two query for this. make it single as given

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' and username='$u' LIMIT 1";